# Best design to create and then use the JDBC statement in threading

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, db2

I am working in an application, where huge number and various kinds of data need to be populated in DB2 tables, in a sufficient amount of time. So I made changes in code to populated the data in different Threads, like this

```
public class ThreadPopulator implements Runnable
{
    volatile private boolean isTaskCompleted;
    volatile private Connection db2Conn;
    volatile private List<Data> list;
    volatile private String srcLib;

    public ThreadPopulator(Connection db2Conn, List<Data> list, String srcLib)
    {
        this.db2Conn = db2Conn;
        this.list = list;
        this.srcLib = srcLib;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            isTaskCompleted = false;
            execute(srcLib, list);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
        }
    }

    synchronized private void execute(String srcLib, List<Data> list)
    {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int len = list.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                if (stmt == null)
                    stmt =
                            db2Conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
                                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
                                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

                Data data = list.get(i);

                stmt.setString(1, srcLib);
                stmt.setString(2, "VV");
                stmt.setDouble(3, data.getSeq());
                stmt.setInt(4, data.getDate());

                stmt.addBatch();

                if ((i + 1) % 5000 == 0)
                    stmt.executeBatch(); // Execute every 5000 items.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if (len > 0)
                stmt.executeBatch();  //for remaining records
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            stmt.close();
            if (list != null) list.clear();
            isTaskCompleted = true;
        }
    }

    public static ThreadPopulator insert(Connection db2Conn, ArrayList<Data> list, String srcLib)
    {
        ThreadPopulator populator = new ThreadPopulator(db2Conn, srcLib);
        Thread thread = new Thread(populator);
        thread.start();
        return populator;
    }
}
```

Then I got the error: **DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-805, SQLSTATE=51002, SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSLH21E**. Means number of opened statements exceeds the limit which is around 13K, so I made some logging to see how many statement are being created (by incrementing a static counter on prepareStatement() and by decrementing on close()), and found no decrementing is taking place, since close() is not called and the total statements count is reached to 22K.

So I finally made some changes to create a static statement object and to use that instance in all threads as

```
private static PreparedStatement stmt = null;
public static void createStatement(Connection db2Conn)
    {
        try
        {
            if (stmt == null)
            {
                stmt =
                            db2Conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DATA VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
                                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
                                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Now everything is working fine. But as a Java developer, I am not happy with this technique. i.e. Creating a static variable and then use that object in all threads.**

> Could you please suggest me what would be the best design to
>   create/use the statement in threading and also it works for my case as
>   well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The common practice in these situations is to use some sort of [connection pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html); the database driver needs to implement this feature. You can find info on the DB2 implementation at IBM's [DB2 documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc/doc/cjvjpool.htm).

Comment: Yes u pointed out the correct thing but can u look the code, why the close() not executed, to reduce the nbr of opened statements??

Comment: No, I'm not really sure about that. Can you show where and how you added your logging statements? It's possible, for example, that you put the logging in the wrong places. You should also never blindly catch and discard `Exception`s and `Throwable`s like you are here. Anything could be happening in this code and you'd never know.